# asp.net MVC não reconhece datas em dd/mm/yyyy recebidas via GET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

Eu estou fazendo um filtro para uma lista paginada. Os valores deste filtro devem ser enviados via ajax com verb GET.

Esse é o model:

```
public class FiltroViewModel
{
    public DateTime? CriadosDe { get;set; }
    public DateTime? CriadosAte { get;set; }
}
```

Essa é a view: (não sei se faz diferença, mas eu uso eternicode bootstrap-datepicker)

```
<form class="form-horizontal" data-form-filter>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CriadosDe, "{0:d}", new { @class = "input-sm form-control" })
                <span class="input-group-addon">Até</span>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CriadosAte, "{0:d}", new { @class = "input-sm form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Jquery

```
var formData = $(document).find('[data-form-filter]').serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    data: formData,
    success: function (data) {
      fazAlgo();
    }, 
});
```

Supondo um CriadosDe = 04/10/2016 e um CriadosAte = 28/10/2016, a serialização fica assim:

```
&CriadosDe=04%2F10%2F2016&CriadosAte=28%2F10%2F2016
```

O problema é que o model chega com esses valores no controller:

```
CriadosDe = 10/04/2016
CriadosAte = null
```

Ou seja, o servidor tentou interpretar como mm/dd/yyyy. Como fazê-lo interpretar sempre como dd/mm/yyyy?

Comment: Já tentou trocar o `DateTime` por `String`?

Comment: Putz, excelente ideia, não tinha pensado nisso ainda! Deixar como string já resolve tudo, mesmo. Obrigado. De qualquer forma, vamos ver se aparece uma resposta pra usar o DateTime.

Comment: Fiz uma Pergunta, veja: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/156655/varchar-ou-datetime?noredirect=1#comment323008_156655

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece porque as requisições GET são tratadas pelo model binder padrão e ele utiliza CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, diferente das requisições POST que usam a CultureInfo da aplicação.

No caso você tem as seguintes alternativas

- Não utilizar GET
- Utilizar GET e mudar o formato na hora de colocar no link/URL
- Mudar de DateTime para String e depois fazer o devido tratamento no controle (como foi sugerido pelo @Marconi)