# Varchar ou Datetime?

Tags: sql, data

Sempre salvo minhas datas no banco usando o tipo [datetime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187819(v=sql.120).aspx). Ao exibir essas datas em uma aplicação, faço algo como:

`select Convert(Varchar, GETDATE(),103) Data`

Resultado: *04/10/2016*

- Gostaria de entender porque usamos `datetime` em vez de `varchar`? Nesse caso eu não precisaria usar um Cast na exibição ao usuário!
- A alguma implicação de desempenho envolvido?
- Existem vantagens?

**Obs:** Se possível dê exemplos.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759012/when-to-use-varchar-and-date-datetime. (Não leia somente a primeira ou mais votada resposta. Leia todas)

Comment: Importante entender que quando você guarda um valor em datetime, normalmente os dados não são guardados textualmente. Não é salvo `2016-10-04 00:00:00`, mas sim o equivalente numérico que representa a data e a hora, que é muito mais eficiente em termos de espaço e velocidade para cálculos e comparações.

Comment: @DanielOmine vou acabar a leitura e dá minhas opiniões por aqui.

Comment: @Bacco não quer criar uma resposta?

Comment: @Marconi as respostas dadas acho que já são abrangentes o suficiente, só complementei para enfatizar este ponto.

Comment: @Bacco Entendi, eu não sabia que a data era representada por um numero, seria algo como um bite?

Comment: @Marconi No MyISAM, se eu não me engano, são usados 12 bits para o ano, 4 para o mês, e 8 bits para o dia, totalizando 3 bytes (para a parte da data). Outros engines podem guardar como um número absoluto em segundos, de uma data determinada, por exemplo. Aí varia de implementação para implementação. Tem sistemas que usam float, sendo a parte fracionária as horas, e as inteiras o número de dias de uma data de referência (por exemplo, 283.5 seria meio dia, e 285 dias depois da data de referência inicial). SQLite mesmo não tem um tipo dedicado de data, mas tem funções de timestamp para conversão

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema de utilizar um campo data de como `varchar` é na hora de ordernar,

```
CREATE TABLE `datas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data_varchar` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

*Inserts:*

```
INSERT INTO `datas` VALUES (1,'30/01/2015','2015-01-30',NULL),
(2,'29/01/2015','2015-01-29',NULL),
(3,'30/03/2015','2015-03-30',NULL),
(4,'29/03/2015','2015-03-29',NULL),
(5,'28/04/2015','2015-04-28',NULL),
(6,'28/02/2015','2015-02-28',NULL),
(7,'27/02/2015','2015-02-27',NULL),
(8,'31/12/2015','2015-12-31',NULL),
(9,'30/12/2015','2015-12-31',NULL)
```

Utilizei o MySQL como exemplo (apersar da pergunta mostra o SQL Server) também funciona.

Ordenação como `data_varchar` veja os dias vem primeiro independente do mês (linhas 2 e 3)

Consulta:

```
select data_varchar, date_format(data_date, '%d/%m/%Y') from datas order by  data_varchar
```

Resultado:

```
data_varchar|data_date
27/02/2015  |27/02/2015
28/02/2015  |28/02/2015
28/04/2015  |28/04/2015
29/01/2015  |29/01/2015
29/03/2015  |29/03/2015
30/01/2015  |30/01/2015
30/03/2015  |30/03/2015
30/12/2015  |31/12/2015
31/12/2015  |31/12/2015
```

Ordenação com `data_date` veja que agora o data foi ordenada como o esperado primeiro o menor dia do mês (29/01) e o seguinte (30/01) e depois passou para o mês seguinte (02).

Consulta:

```
select data_varchar, date_format(data_date, '%d/%m/%Y') from datas order by data_date
```

Resultado:

```
data_varchar|data_date
29/01/2015  |29/01/2015
30/01/2015  |30/01/2015
27/02/2015  |27/02/2015
28/02/2015  |28/02/2015
29/03/2015  |29/03/2015
30/03/2015  |30/03/2015
28/04/2015  |28/04/2015
31/12/2015  |31/12/2015
30/12/2015  |31/12/2015
```

Comment: Ou seja, se preferir usar `VARCHAR` ao invés de `DATETIME`, não me chame para trabalhar nesse projeto depois, que eu tô fora :p

Comment: @WallaceMaxters exatamente isso, da pra contonar isso ... já edito.

Answer (score 4):

De cara, a primeira vantagem que posso falar sobre `DATETIME` é que, na hora de comparar intervalos entre datas, você dispensa o uso de funções para fazer conversões para se achar um resultado.

Exemplo

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE date >= '2015-10-02 00:00:00' <= '2017-12-02 00:00:00'
```

Outra vantagem é que geralmente os SGBD que te permite definir o tipo `DATETIME` não vai permitir que uma data seja inserida erradamente. É claro, que vai depender de como também está configurado.

Agora, se você quiser usar `VARCHAR` ao invés de `DATETIME`, prepare-se:

- Você não pode facilmente somar/subtrair dias para a versão VARCHAR.
- É mais difícil de extrair apenas mês/ano.
- Não há nada que impeça você colocar os dados não-data na coluna VARCHAR no banco de dados.
- Você não pode facilmente ordenar por datas.
- É difícil mudar o formato, se você quiser mais tarde. (OS SGBDs possui funções específicas para trabalhar com datas)
- É pouco convencional, o que vai tornar mais difícil para outros desenvolvedores entender o que você fez.
- Isso vai afetar no tamanho em disco utilizado. `VARCHAR` vai usar mais espaço de armazenamento. Isto pode não importa para pequenas quantidades de dados, mas em ambientes comerciais com milhões de linhas de dados isso poderia fazer uma grande diferença.

Fonte: [When to use VARCHAR and DATE/DATETIME](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4759039/3096922)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Wallace Maxters.

Comment: De nada, @Marconi. Estamos aqui para ajudar :)