# Ordenar consulta por data

Tags: php, mysql

Como posso ordenar uma consulta por data?

```
SELECT * FROM agenda ORDER BY evento ASC
```

Dessa maneira está aparecendo do seguinte modo:
30/03/2017, 31/05/2016 (a data com o ano de 2016 deveria aparecer primeiro).

Comment: A data está como varchar? converta ela para date na hora de ordernar. Relacionado: [Varchar ou Datetime?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156655/91)

Comment: @rray, fiz da maneira que o juniorb2ss sugeriu, deu tudo certo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guilherme, para conseguir ordernar por data o campo `evento` é necessário estar com o tipo `datetime`.

Caso o campo esteja com o tipo string, você precisará converter essa data para uma instância de data e assim efetuar manipulação.

`SELECT * FROM agenda ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(evento, '%d/%m/%Y') ASC`

Referência:

> STR_TO_DATE(str,format)
>   STR_TO_DATE (str, format) Este é o inverso da função DATE_FORMAT (). É preciso uma string str e um formato de string. STR_TO_DATE () retorna um valor DATETIME se a sequência de caracteres de formato conter partes de data e hora, ou um valor DATE ou TIME se a sequência de caracteres contém somente partes de data ou hora. Se a data, hora ou valor de data / hora extraídos de str é ilegal, STR_TO_DATE () retorna NULL e produz um aviso.
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

## Sugestão

É recomendado que caso o campo `evento` esteja como tipo `varchar()` você troque para o tipo `datetime`, pois é o jeito correto e você terá muitas funcionalidades disponiveis no MySQL para trabalhar com este campo.

Veja maiores detalhes nessa outra resposta: [Varchar ou Datetime?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/156655/varchar-ou-datetime)

Comment: Não só "muito mais funcionalidades" como o `DATETIME` terá uma performance muito melhor. O `STR_TO_DATE()` será feito a cada chamada em cada linha, é insano utilizar isto. A melhor solução é passar para `DATETIME` ou `TIMESTAMP` ou no máximo `INT`.

Comment: @Inkeliz muito bem colocado.