# Como postar data e hora utilizando o tipo ''datatime'' no sql

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados, datetime

PHP:

```
$date = new DateTime();
print_r ($date);
```

resultado:

```
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2017-11-07 15:51:26.000000 [timezone_type] => 3
[timezone] => America/Sao_Paulo )
```

OK ate aí.

Banco de dados (sql). Tabela "extras":

[image: Tabela "extras"]

Preciso saber qual padrão o tipo datetime utiliza, para saber como postar as informações de data e hora no banco.

Abaixo os testes realizados, e as respostas obtidas:

TESTE 1:

```
 $postdate = $conect -> query("INSERT INTO extras (data) values ('{$date['date']}')");
```

[image]

TESTE 2:

```
$postdate = $conect -> query("INSERT INTO extras (data) values ('{$date}')");
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde ja agradeço

Comment: tem que modificar para o modo EUA de data para inserir no banco de dados Y-m-d, correto @rray ?

Comment: Sim, pode usar apenas `$data = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Comment: Acho que tem algo que não esta entrando na minha cabeça. Se eu usar "$data = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');", quando eu recuperar as informações será apenas uma string qualquer. Para usar assim não faria diferença utilizar o datetime, ou um varchar.

Comment: vc não precisa gravar no banco um objeto DateTime do php, se gravar como varchar não vai ordernar nem pesquisar corretamente os resultados. Relacioanda: [Varchar ou Datetime?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156655/91)

Answer (score 1):

Existe várias funções para gravar a data no SQL, uma que eu utilizo seria o CURDATE(); ele pega a data atual. Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
  $postdate = $conect -> query("INSERT INTO extras (data) values (CURDATE());
```

Observação: Curdate() por padrão irá retornar Ano/Dia/Mês.
Caso queira formatar, utilize:

```
  date_format(curdate(), '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

O objeto `DateTime` não tem cast pra `string`. Por isso é necessário usar o método `format` pra exibir a data na saída desejada.

O formato usado no MYSQL para inserir datas é `Y-m-d H:i:s`.

```
$sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO tabela (data) VALUES ("%s")', $data->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

$query->execute($sql)
```

Por outro lado, se for inserir a data atual, pode ser legal você usar `NOW()` ao invés de ficar convertendo do PHP.

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO tabela (data) VALUES(NOW())';
```